# Recalculate Counter Cache of 120k Records [Rails / ActiveRecord]

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The following situation:

I have a poi model, which has many pictures (1:n). I want to recalculate the counter_cache column, because the values are inconsistent.

I've tried to iterate within ruby over each record, but this takes much too long and quits sometimes with some "segmentation fault" bugs.

So i wonder, if its possible to do this with a raw sql query?

Answer (score 8):

If, for example, you have `Post` and `Picture` models, and post `has_many :pictures`, you can do it with `update_all` :

```
Post.update_all("pictures_count=(Select count(*) from pictures where pictures.post_id=posts.id)")
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a nice solution on [krautcomputing](https://www.krautcomputing.com/blog/2015/01/13/recalculate-counter-cache-columns-in-rails/).
It uses reflections to find all counter caches of a project, SQL queries to find only the objects that are inconsistent and use Rails reset_counters to clean things up.

Unfortunately it only works with "conventional" counter caches (no class name, no custom counter cache names) so I refined it:

```ruby
Rails.application.eager_load!

ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.each do |many_class|
  many_class.reflections.each do |name, reflection|
    if reflection.options[:counter_cache]
      one_class = reflection.class_name.constantize
      one_table, many_table = [one_class, many_class].map(&:table_name)
      # more reflections, use :inverse_of, :counter_cache etc.
      inverse_of = reflection.options[:inverse_of]
      counter_cache = reflection.options[:counter_cache]
      if counter_cache === true
        counter_cache = "#{many_table}_count"
        inverse_of ||= many_table.to_sym
      else
        inverse_of ||= counter_cache.to_s.sub(/_count$/,'').to_sym
      end
      ids = one_class
        .joins(inverse_of)
        .group("#{one_table}.id")
        .having("MAX(#{one_table}.#{counter_cache}) != COUNT(#{many_table}.id)")
        .pluck("#{one_table}.id")
      ids.each do |id|
        puts "reset #{id} on #{many_table}"
        one_class.reset_counters id, inverse_of
      end
    end
  end
end
```